# run a code on calculating the euler method for ODE

Tags: matlab

```
function yout = eulermethod(myeuler, t0, h, tf, y0)

 tic

    yout = y0 
    y = yout;

    for t = t0 : h : tf
        s = myeuler(t,y);
        y = y + h*s;
        y = y(2)
        yout = [yout; y]
        plot(t,yout)
    toc
    end

end
```

Igot this error
Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in eulermethod (line 9)
        s = myeuler(t,y

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in eulermethod (line 9)
        s = myeuler(t,y

Comment: I got this error

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Before posting, read the help. This is not a  [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. We don't know what myeuler(t,y) is. Is it a method?  A matrix?

Comment: function dydt = myeuler(t,y)
    t =0;
    y =10;
    dydt = 2*y 
    
end
this is another function

Comment: it's something with the code that I can not find by help. myeuler is another function which i have called in the code and i wrote it above

Comment: We don't see `myeuler` so we can't see what's in it.

Comment: You should edit your initial question with all the needed info, don't write important info in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that MATLAB thinks `myeuler` is a matrix rather than a function. When you call `eulermethod`, I assume you are doing something like

```
yout = eulermethod(myeuler, t0, h, tf, y0);
```

What you actually want to be doing is

```
yout = eulermethod(@myeuler, t0, h, tf, y0);
```

The @ turns the first argument into a function handle (see [the matlab documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html)).

There are other issues with the rest of the code but I'm not exactly sure what equation you're trying to solve so I can't help too much. Certainly, your plot line doesn't make much sense as `t` is a scalar.

Assuming you're solving the differential equation dy/dt = 2y, for y(t=0) = y0, your functions should look a bit like

```
function dydt = myeuler(t,y)
dydt = 2*y;
end      

function yout = eulermethod(myeuler, t0, h, tf, y0)

    yout = y0;
    y = y0;

    for t = (t0+h):h:tf

        s = myeuler(t,y);
        y = y + h*s;
        yout = [yout; y];

        plot(t0:h:t, yout) 
        xlabel('t');
        ylabel('y');

        pause(0.1);

    end

end
```

And would then be called by some code like

```
t0 = 0;
h = 0.01;
tf = 1;
y0 = 1.0;

yout = eulermethod(@myeuler, t0, h, tf, y0);
```